# Illustrator - Delete everything that's outside Objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do I delete all the unnecessary white shapes, only keep the ones on the logo itself.

[image]

[image]

Comment: And... https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25818/how-to-punch-through-all-the-layers-in-adobe-illustrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your texture is all vectors and you literally mean you want to delete all extra points outside your logo object... I'm a fan of this method:

1. Start with 2 groups. [A group with the texture and a group with the logo object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B81tx.png).
2. Duplicate the part of the logo object you want to apply the texture to...

   - Duplicate: <kbd>Cmd + C</kbd> → <kbd>Cmd + F</kbd>
   - This duplicate will essentially become the cookie cutter
3. `Object > Expand Appearance` (If applicable)
4. `Object > Expand`
5. `Window > Pathfinder` flyout menu `Make compound shape`
6. [`Window > Pathfinder` → <kbd>Expand</kbd> (Progress image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hg8o.png).

   - The original logo object is somewhere below the two visible groups.
7. With the texture below the cookie cutter, select both and then do `Window > Pathfinder` → `Crop` ...and you get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMq5G.png).

You're left with 2 groups. [The original logo object and a texture that is cut to the shape of the logo object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jXwV.png).

---

You may also need to do steps 3 and 4 on the texture as well... Like if the texture is made with a brush for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Using a *Clipping Mask*;

Create a circle until your edges and make sure it's on top of all other objects.

*Select all* and **Right click → Make Clipping Mask**

---

I've explained how clipping masks work in **[this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/102191/63979)**.

You can also read more about clipping masks at [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html).