# How do I remove original shape outline created by Clipping Mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I tried my best to crop out a part of an svg and I thought I had got it working, but when selecting the outside, I could still see the original shape. I used the rectangle tool and went to `Object > Clipping Mask > Create` to create this effect. I tried deleting the excess from the layer system and saving the cut off shape as an svg but to no avail. Here is an image of what I am talking about:

[image]

How do I remove the outline in blue?

Comment: `Window > Pathfinder`

Comment: Thanks the intercept option worked. Can you post it as an answer so I can approve it? @Joonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Method 1:

You can clip objects with other objects with [`Window > Pathfinder`](https://helpx.adobe.com/fi/illustrator/using/creating-shapes-shape-builder-tool.html).

- You need to select the shape you want to clip and the clipping object before using Pathfinder.
- In this case `Intersect` or `Minus back` are probably what you want to use depending on how you want to perform the clipping.
- You can see the names/descriptions by hovering over each icon for a couple of seconds.
- **Intersect** - Erase everything *outside* the front object.
- **Minus back** - Erase everything *inside* the front object.

#### Method 2:

You could also possibly use the [`Shape builder tool (Shift+M)`](https://helpx.adobe.com/fi/illustrator/using/creating-shapes-shape-builder-tool.html), which is basically the same thing but in a brush form.

- `Alt` key allows you to minus from the shape. You just kinda scribble over the parts you want to remove. Pathfinder may be less work.

#### Method 3:

And possibly even [`Object > Path > Divide object below`](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/cutting-dividing-objects.html#Commandsforcuttinganddividingobjects)

- Basically the same as `Pathfinder > Divide`

Comment: I'll put this here since it's somewhat related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117802/illustrator-delete-everything-thats-outside-objects/117827#117827